# How to simulate water in a bottle type of physics using accelerometer using Corona SDK?

Tags: ios, coronasdk, accelerometer, game-physics

I'm developing a gaming application where the user must shake his or her iphone to get objects to move around hitting the borders of the phone.  Similar to how water behaves in a bottle.

I know that we can tilt the device to cause a pinball effect, but can we shake the device like shaking a bottle of water?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Accelerometer, you can get parameters you need. And in every frame, according to parameters, you can change gravity or apply force to physics objects.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/accelerometer/index.html

I recommend you to use Instant parameters. You can change gravity according to that.